# dynamic routing based on request parameter in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, dynamic-routing

I am building a RESTful API using expressJS, In my controller I have several functions like Chall_1, Chall_2,...

```
exports.validateChall_1 = function(res) {
//logic
  res.json(1);
};
exports.validateChall_2 = function(res) {
    res.json(2);
};
exports.validateChall_3 = function(res) {
    res.json(3);
};
```

in my router.js I want to route the URL to a specific function based on challId which is a parameter in url

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
  var jsvalidator = require('../controllers/jsvalidatorController');
  app.route('/chall/:challId')
    .get(/*jsvalidator.validateChall_ + req.params.challId*/);
};
```

Is it possible to route directly to a specific function based on challId parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like

```
app.route('/chall/:challId')
  .get(function (req, res, next) {
      switch (req.params.challId) {
        case 1:
         ctrl.validate_chall1(req, res, next);
         break;
        case 2:
         ctrl.validate_chall2();
         break;
        default:
         next() //it should continue to 404 route
         break;
  }
});
```

but I think doing this is better to keep the routes clean

```
app.route('/chall/challId/validate')
   .get(ctrl.validate)

//in ctrl 
function validate(req, res, next){
  if(req.params.challId === 1)
    validate_ctrl1()
  //etc
}
```